# Forgotten Documents in Grad School Applications

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am applying for grad schools in the US for mathematics PhD programs.

I studied in Ireland and as a result, was asked to upload English translations of all documents.

My degree certificates are in Latin. I have only just realised this now, and it's a week past the submission date for the schools I applied for.

I have ordered an English translation, and intend to send this on when I receive it.

Is this something that can affect the outcome of an application? If so, is there anything I could do to improve the situation?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot ask the program?

Comment: Also, could you do something differently if somebody says it can affect the outcome?

Comment: I think that if someone is interested in you, they will ask for translations at a later point. Also, as suggested, why not ask them via email?

Comment: If the institutions you're applying to are anything like mine, none of the mathematicians evaluating your application will care about a late translation. The only possible problem that I can see is that a clerical worker might not pass your application on to the math department until the translation arrives. Then the mathematicians will sigh, say something like "Bureaucracy strikes again!" and consider your application along with the others as if nothing had happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should contact the institution(s), apologize for misunderstanding requirements and offer to send the proper documents when available. Mention that you have requested them. Ask if there is anything else you can do and whether this will affect your application.

It is impossible to say what will happen but it is all you can do at the moment. I suspect that it can be resolved, but can't guarantee it.